# docker compose logs follow not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose on mac and since a recent docker update my `docker-compose logs -f` is displaying logs but not following, once the logs displayed the process is stopped.

I am only using docker compose on local

```
Docker Compose version v2.0.0-beta.6
```

```
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

From time to time when running `docker-compose logs` I have `Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading` I do not know if this is related.

Comment: Docker-compose v2 is in beta and there are some peculiar issues with it on Github. Try disabling it and see if it helps `docker-compose disable-v2`.